# HIbernate - bulk loading child objects

Tags: nhibernate, bulk-load

How can I get NHibernate to hook up child objects automatically or bulk load children rather than lazy loading for each parent?

I have a large number of parent objects all of the same type. Each of them has two bags of child objects. As I need to load all the parents and children objects as quickly as possible, I use NHibernate to load all the objects and then loop all child objects and add them to relevant parent in code. I'm sure NHibernate has a much better way of doing this - but what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use eager loading behavior of NHibernate to override its default behavior (Lazy Loading).
[Here](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/lazy-loading-eager-loading.aspx) is an article that discuss lazy loading and eagerly loading

Take a look at the "Eagerly loading with HQL" part that shows how you can use HQL to eagerly load an object graph.

However using eager loading can have a negative impact on performance specially if you are working with a lot of objects.

Comment: The link is dead. Please replace the link.